# "Help with" title restriction present in edit, but not original posting

Tags: bug, edits, title, question-restrictions

I was just trying to remove some of the noise from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518008/i-seek-a-professional-help-with-smsc-smpp-connection), then it complained that "Help with" may not appear in the title.

It seems like a bug that there's a restriction in editing that's not present in original posting of the question. Am I correct? Can this be fixed (or changed if it's by-design)?

Since the question was posted just a few minutes ago, it being a feature that has been implemented after the question was posted seems unlikely.

Comment: Really this should be titled "Help with 'help with'"

Comment: I am tempted to try to remove "Help With" here to see if it gives me an error